# Foreign Key Restraints being ignored MySQL workbench

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

I'm using MySQL Workbench and I'm for some reason having problems getting FK restraints working.

Here is the MySQL code I'm using to try to test if the foreign key restraint is working.

```
create table users(user_id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, username VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL, password VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL);
create table posts(user_id INT NOT NULL, CONSTRAINT fk_posts_user_id FOREIGN KEY(user_id) REFERENCES users(user_id), post_id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, post_content VARCHAR(2000) NOT NULL, number_comments INT NOT NULL);
create table comments(user_id INT NOT NULL, CONSTRAINT fk_comments_user_id FOREIGN KEY(user_id) REFERENCES users(user_id), post_id INT NOT NULL, CONSTRAINT fk_comments_post_id FOREIGN KEY(post_id) REFERENCES posts(post_id), comment_id INT PRIMARY KEY, comment_content VARCHAR(2000) NOT NULL);
insert into users VALUES(NULL, "user1", "pass1");
insert into posts VALUES(4, NULL, "content1", 0);
```

I've looked at other posts regarding this and I've tried the following:

- Checked if "select @@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS" is set to 1
- Changed my code to use the CONSTRAINT fk__ method

Is there anything I'm missing? Thanks!

Comment: Are you using the InnoDB or MyISAM engine? MyISAM doesn't check foreign keys.

Comment: That's it. Thanks!